# How do you or can you control the visual orientation of the results of a matrix project

Tags: jenkins

I created a matrix project to control code testing that has 3 axes representing 1) a suite of tests, 2) the machine architecture, and 3) another config parameter. The project does what I want it to do, which is dispatch each test to the correct node and run the test scripts using the config parameter. What I would like is to control how the results matrix is displayed.

When I created the project, it appeared that I could control the visual presentation depending on the order each axis was defined. However, once I restarted Jenkins, the results matrix was displayed as a long narrow matrix (minimal columns, many rows).

I would prefer to have the results matrix displayed as a wider matrix (more columns, less rows).

Is there a way to control how jenkins displays the axes?

Comment: Found my own answer. Seems that jenkins applies axes alphabetically. The 1st axis (AXIS_0) is displayed horizontally. The remaining axes (AXIS_N...) are displayed vertically in order, left to right. Therefore, to control placement, you need only to name your axes accordingly.